# Style not being applied

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I have an html menu, that start like this:

```
<nav id='main'>
<ul>
```

and my CSS file goes like this:

```
nav #main ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

But for some reason, this does not seem to work...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing the space between 'nav' and '#main' in your CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using

```
nav#main ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

ie remove the space between `nav` and `#main` - using the space is indicating `#main` is a descendant of `nav` instead of saying `#main` is an id attribute of `nav`

[See the docs here for pattern matching in CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching)

Answer (score 6):

Space is [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

You are trying to apply this style to:

- All the `<ul>` descendants from an object with `id="main"` that is descendant of a `<nav>` object.

You should instead apply the style to:

- All the `<ul>` descendants from a `<nav>` object with `id="main"`.

It can be done removing the first space:

```
nav#main ul {
   list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space

```
nav#main ul {
   list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it really should be

```
nav#main ul { }
```

Comment: Haha, thank you! I'm sitll quite new to making my own layouts :D